# Apache Camel iterate over List

Tags: spring, apache, rest, apache-camel, integration

I am new to Apache Camel and I am having problems understanding how to implement a simple integration task:

1. A REST service is calling a Spring Bean through Apache Camel route
2. Spring Bean returns a collection of classes (ArrayList)

I need to iterate over each item in the collection and convert it to another type through the custom converter.

It seems that I should use Split and an Aggregator, but how do I constraint Aggregator to consume all items from the original list, not more, nor less. Also, how can I convert one item to another? Should I use a Type Converter?

Can someone provide me a simple example?

*UPDATE 1*

Sorry, I had to undo acceptance of the provided example since it is not actually answering to my question. Here is the use case qualification:
I need to split and transform a method return value from `to("bean:someBean")` invocation rather than split and transform input values from some endpoint.

So the use case is

1. Call some endpoint; e.g a GET request on rest service, in my case: `from("endpoint")`
2. Call a bean and get it's return value; like `List`, `to("bean:someBean")`)
3. Transform returned value to another `List`
4. Return transformed `List` to consumer

*UPDATE 2*

So, I can confirm than using `end()` method does not solve my problem.

Here is the code:

```
rest("some/service").get().produces("application/json").to("bean:someBean?method=getListOfObjects").route().split(body(), (oldExchange, newExchange) -> {
                List<ObjectToConvert> oldList = oldExchange.getIn(List.class);
                List<NewObject> convertedList = taskList.stream().map(ObjectToConvert::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
                newExchange.getOut().setBody(convertedList);

                return newExchange;
            }).end();
```

Using this kind of route I get the following exception on the application server:

```
19:30:21,126 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (XNIO-1 task-5) JBAS014613: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: (undefined) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./CamundaLearningCamel" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./CamundaLearningCamel: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2 at: >>> Split[{body} -> []] <<< in route: Route(route2)[[From[rest:get:task/all?produces=application%2... because of Definition has no children on Split[{body} -> []]
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2 at: >>> Split[{body} -> []] <<< in route: Route(route2)[[From[rest:get:task/all?produces=application%2... because of Definition has no children on Split[{body} -> []]
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2 at: >>> Split[{body} -> []] <<< in route: Route(route2)[[From[rest:get:task/all?produces=application%2... because of Definition has no children on Split[{body} -> []]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Definition has no children on Split[{body} -> []]"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete example that splits aggregates and converts a list message.

1. The camel splitter provides a built-in aggregator which aggregates
   all split messages in the original exchange. So the splitter is only
   aggregating the messages of each list(exchange) send in "direct:start". You have to provide a custom
   aggregation strategy because the default one will use the original
   exchanges, in my example InOrder. The aggregation strategy is the
   second argument of the split definition.
2. The type converter gives us the opportunity to use convertBodyTo in
   DSL. You cound also achieve that with a bean,processor or do all the transformations in the custom aggregation strategy.

   ```
   package org.mydemocamel.app;
   import org.apache.camel.*;
   import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
   import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
   import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;
   import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy;
   import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.UseLatestAggregationStrategy;
   import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.UseOriginalAggregationStrategy;
   import org.apache.camel.support.TypeConverterSupport;
   import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
   import org.apache.camel.util.toolbox.FlexibleAggregationStrategy;
   import org.junit.Test;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;


   public class CamelSplitAggregateConvertTest extends CamelTestSupport {

       @Produce
       private ProducerTemplate template;

       @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:out")
       private MockEndpoint mock;

       @Test
       public void testSplitAggregateConvertOrder(){
           InOrder inOrder1 = new InOrder();
           inOrder1.setId("1");

           InOrder inOrder2 = new InOrder();
           inOrder2.setId("2");

           List<InOrder> inOrderList = new ArrayList<InOrder>();
           inOrderList.add(inOrder1);
           inOrderList.add(inOrder2);

           template.sendBody("direct:start", inOrderList);

           mock.expectedMessageCount(1);
           Exchange outList = mock.getReceivedExchanges().get(0);
           List<OutOrder> outOrderList = outList.getIn().getBody(List.class);

           assertEquals(1, outOrderList.get(0).getId());
           assertEquals(2, outOrderList.get(1).getId());


       }

       @Override
       protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
           return new RouteBuilder() {
               @Override
               public void configure() throws Exception {

                   context.getTypeConverterRegistry().addTypeConverter(OutOrder.class, InOrder.class, new MyOrderTypeConverter());

                   from("direct:start")
                   .split(body(), new AggregationStrategy() {
                       @Override
                       public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                           if (oldExchange == null) {
                               List<OutOrder> orders = new ArrayList<OutOrder>();
                               OutOrder newOrder = newExchange.getIn().getBody(OutOrder.class);
                               orders.add(newOrder);
                               newExchange.getIn().setBody(orders);
                               return newExchange;
                           }
                           List<OutOrder> orders = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                           OutOrder newOutOrder = newExchange.getIn().getBody(OutOrder.class);
                           orders.add(newOutOrder);
                           oldExchange.getIn().setBody(orders);
                           return oldExchange;
                       }
                   })
                   .convertBodyTo(OutOrder.class)
                   .end()  //splitter ends here and the exchange body  is now List<OutOrder> 
                   .to("mock:out");

               }
           };
       }

       private static class MyOrderTypeConverter extends TypeConverterSupport {

           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
           public <T> T convertTo(Class<T> type, Exchange exchange, Object value) {
               // converter from inorder to outorder bean
               OutOrder order = new OutOrder();
               order.setId(Integer.parseInt(((InOrder) value).getId()));
               return (T) order;
           }
       }

       private static class OutOrder {
           private int id;

           public void setId(int id) {
               this.id = id;
           }

           public int getId() {
               return id;
           }
       }

       private static class InOrder {
           private String id;

           public void setId(String id) {
               this.id = id;
           }

           public String getId() {
               return id;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This example is does not fully cover my case: I need to split and transform method return value from `to("bean:someBean")` invovation rather than split and transform input values from endpoint. So the case is 1) call some endpoint (rest in my case, `from("endpoint")`) 2) call some bean and get it's return value (it's List, `to("bean:someBean")` 3) transform returned value to another List

Comment: You can do .to("bean:someBean").split(body(),)...... There is no difference if you use the direct endpoint, like .to(bean:someBean).to(direct:start). Direct endpoint provides synchronous invocation when connecting routes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't because split can not be the last activity in the exchange.

Comment: I cannot seem to understand where is the problem.The last activity will be the return of the transformed list. Based on your update step 2) is Call some bean and get it's return value (it's List, to("bean:someBean")). My example is step 3 and 4. So after step 2 send the exhange to my (direct:start). The end of the route is .end(). The aggregated list will be returned to the rest consumer is step 1. In my previous comment I mentioned that you can use a different route or not, just append all the route part from .split(body()..aggregate()..transform()...end(). in the same route.

Comment: I have not known about the `end()` method. Thank you, I will try to use it and write if it works.

Comment: Please, see *UPDATE 2*. Unfortunately Using `end()` does not help.

Comment: In your example you are just transforming Lists using plain java, but aggregator does not work like this. You have 2 options:
 1) Just perform this kind of transformation inside getListOfObjects method or another method after it and avoid using camel split/aggregate for that. THis will work as you expect now.  
 2) Update your code according to my example PRECISELY which will work for your case and study carefully the [Split aggregate request/reply sample] section in https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html to understand the details about Splitting/Aggregating messages using Camel.Hope I helped.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, another way you can iterate over a list is using the `loop` construct of the Java DSL. Here's an example:

```
from("direct:myDirect")
.loop(header("LIST_LENGTH")) // You will set this header in the processor before with the list lenght.
.process(new Processor(){

      @Override
      public void proocess(Exchange arg0){
          MyObj currentElement = (MyObj) arg0.getIn().getBody(List.class).get(LOOP_INDEX);
          // Do your processing here.
      }
})
.end()
.end();
```

The `LOOP_INDEX` property will contain the current iteration, starting from 0 up to the LIST_LENGHT header value, so you can use it to get the current element from the list.

Notice the double `end()` method call: one is for ending the loop and the other one is to end the route.

Documentation: http://camel.apache.org/loop.html

Comment: where is LOOP_INDEX coming from?

Answer (score 1):

you are right with splitter and aggregator, the "Split aggregate request/reply sample" from http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html shows what you need.

Do you need a "converted" list of objects after the splitter?
If yes, the point "Using a List in AggregationStrategy" from http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html looks right for your needs.

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: Thanks, but I can not see how I should write completion predicate, so that Aggregator will wait only for `inputList.size()` messages to come