# Apache Camel - Aggregation split elements to a list

Tags: java, apache-camel

**Problem :**

I first have a list of cages, where I retrieve individually with a split the positions of those ones.

The following consumer get cages already one by one and the processor extract the position.

```
from("direct:cages-to-positions")
                    .process(new CageToPositionProcessor())
                    .aggregate(body(), new PositionsAggregation())
                    .completionTimeout(1000)
                    .to("mock:test");
```

After that, I wan't to get them back into a list, so I use the following aggregation.

```
public class PositionsAggregation implements AggregationStrategy {
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            List<Map> positions = new ArrayList<Map>();
            positions.add((Map) newExchange.getIn().getBody());
            newExchange.getOut().setBody(positions);
            return newExchange;
        }

        Map newPosition = (Map) newExchange.getIn().getBody();
        List<Map> positions = (List<Map>) oldExchange.getIn().getBody();
        positions.add(newPosition);
        oldExchange.getIn().setBody(positions);
        return oldExchange;
    }
}
```

When I am debugging, I can see that I got the right ending oldExchange, but anyway the result in the mock is not the list at all :

**Printing the last oldExchange body :**

```
[{latitude=49.305, longitude=1.2157357}, {latitude=49.305142, longitude=1.2154067}]
```

**Mock result :**

```
11191 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor  - >>>> mock://test Exchange[ID-1524074230289-0-6]
11191 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint  - mock://test >>>> 0 : Exchange[ID-1524074230289-0-6] with body: {latitude=49.305, longitude=1.2157357} and headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-1524074230289-0-6}
11192 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor$AggregationTimeoutMap  - Completion timeout triggered for correlation key: {latitude=49.305142, longitude=1.2154067}
11192 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor  - Aggregation complete for correlation key **{latitude=49.305142, longitude=1.2154067}** sending aggregated exchange: Exchange[ID-1524074230289-0-9]
11192 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor  - Processing aggregated exchange: Exchange[ID-1524074230289-0-9]
11192 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor  - >>>> mock://test Exchange[ID-1524074230289-0-9]
11192 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint  - mock://test >>>> 1 : Exchange[ID-1524074230289-0-9] with body: {latitude=49.305142, longitude=1.2154067} and headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-1524074230289-0-9}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example would work with identical incoming bodies.
You should replace the correlation expression from body() to constant(true), since you are not using the build-in aggregator inside a splitter.

So you

1) either refactor to use the build-in aggregator of the splitter e.g

```
.split(body(), new MyAggregationStrategy())
```

and in this case wouldn't need need the completion condition(.completionTimeout()).

This would aggregate all splitted messages in the incoming list. An example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105526/apache-camel-iterate-over-list/27116446#27116446).

or

2) if you like to collect all incoming exchanges within a 1000 period you have to do the following change

```
 .aggregate(constant(true), new PositionsAggregation())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I'm not sure of what the first parameter "correlationExpression" stand for, specially for the constant(true) value, could you help me with that ? Also, why could I see in debug must the correct list built ? In any case, your solution worked!

Comment: Read the camel docs about the correlation Expression https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/aggregate-eip.adoc . As for the the debugger, it probably visited only into the first if(oldExcange always null) and the strategy created two lists with one element each.

Comment: Ok I got it, the part that disturb me was the debugger showing me a list with the two positions, but I think I get hung up and lost myself.